# Can I protect jointly owned assets from my spouse's professional liability?

Tags: united-states, california, liability

My wife is a [medical resident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residency_(medicine)#United_States). She regularly makes complex decisions that could kill someone while she is [chronically sleep deprived](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_resident_work_hours). Obviously, this is dangerous, but it's a nationwide problem that I cannot control.
I worry that my wife will be sued for medical malpractice. My wife's <s>abuser</s> employer supposedly provides insurance for this, but I don't have a lot of faith in that coverage. (They pay her below the local minimum wage, so I expect they also provide substandard insurance.)

**Is there something that I can do to protect our jointly owned assets from being taken as the result of a lawsuit?**
My fear is that my wife will make a mistake as a result of only sleeping an average of 5 hours per night, get sued, and then we lose our house. My income is significantly higher than my wife's. Thus I worry that a lawsuit against her would end up taking assets (like our house) that are jointly owned, but which I am effectively entirely paying for. Thus I would like to know if there are any proactive measures that I could take to prevent this.

Comment: Consult a lawyer in your jurisdiction.  Find out what your liability is and what measures you can take to limit/eliminate it.

Comment: This is probably more suited to https://law.stackexchange.com/. It's not unusual for residents to make shit pay, but it'd be very unusual for the malpractice insurance to be similarly shit. If her employer provides malpractice insurance, you can probably breathe fairly easily on this front.

Comment: My feeling (not 100% certain) is that it's on-topic here, I'll migrate it if it's closed here or the OP requests it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on law.stackexchange

Comment: I don't know if umbrella insurance would cover this, but umbrella insurance is great for people with a nice nest egg and it doesn't cost much.  Worth getting even if it doesn't help here, and you can ask about this kind of coverage.

Comment: One thing to consider is that, because it is a "nationwide problem" as you note, your concerns apply to basically every medical resident.  There are lots and lots of medical residents in the US.  If the danger you describe were real, medical residents would be getting sued left and right.

Comment: Residents are normally included in the malpractice insurance carried by their schools. Check the employment contract to verify and to check limits. For example, UCLA (Geffen School of Medicine) stipulates "The Medical Center shall include residents under the University’s self insurance program with limits of up to $5 million per occurrence for the liability of the resident while acting in the performance of his/her duties or in the course and scope of his/her assignment."

Answer (score 4):

[Plaintiffs in medical malpractice suits rarely target anything other than insurance limits](https://www.medicaleconomics.com/view/could-malpractice-mega-verdict-wipe-you-out). The reason for this is that judges usually will unilaterally reduce awards over those limits to protect the personal assets of the defendant. Attempts to go after a doctor's assets tend to be viewed as vindictive, so it is hard to succeed. Also, most lawyers are not interested in going to trial, which will greatly prolong their payday. They want the quick payoff of an insurance settlement, so the doctor's personal assets almost never become an issue.

That being said, any lawsuit, win or lose, will negatively affect a doctor's career in various ways financially and otherwise, but that's what your wife signed up for when she became a doctor in the United States. I personally know a lot of doctors and none of them have been impoverished by lawsuits. Most of them do have expensive cars, mansions and swimming pools, though.

Concerning your original question, you can protect your assets either by not holding them jointly and putting them in your name instead of hers, or by creating a limited liability company and putting the assets into the LLC.

Comment: the linked article is quite interesting and I think it would be good to quote some of it, in case the link doesn't work in the future

Answer (score 3):

The question as to what legal risks you're realistically facing is better answered by a lawyer, as pointed out in the comments.

You might be overestimating the risk that something happens on your spouse's watch, that the patient sues successfully, and that her insurance would be insufficient.

From a financial point of view, you need to understand a) what kind of medical malpractice insurance you and your spouse would be comfortable with and b) what kind of coverage she currently has by going through the policy documents. If there's a gap, your spouse could get supplemental insurance independent of her employer.

It's worth noting that there are many other kinds of potential liability either of you could be facing, which is usually addressed by umbrella insurance.

For what it's worth

> **States with effective tort reform, such as caps on non-economic damages, have seen a significant decrease in litigation followed by a fall in average premiums. Some of these states are CA**, CO, KS, TX, Alaska, NC, and the Dakotas. Indiana has a process for pre-litigation screening by a panel, apart from a cap on total damages. **Most of these states have seen among the lowest malpractice payouts per capita.** Interestingly, many of these state legislatures have a physician in office.

source: [How to Buy Medical Malpractice Insurance](https://www.whitecoatinvestor.com/how-to-buy-medical-malpractice-insurance/)